# I accidentally didn't remove the installation disk while installing ubuntu, and now it won't install. How can i fix it?

Tags: grub2

After installation, it said to remove the installation disk and restart, but the disk tray wouldn't open. So i restarted anyway, and now it brings me back to the install screen everytime i try to reinstall the program. I can press escape and it brings up the "GNU GRUB  version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1" terminal. I am using a Toshiba Satellite C55D-B5319, which previously had windows 8.1 installed. Any help on what can be done with this? Any response is greatly appreciated

Comment: It's unclear. Do you have the operating system installed on the HDD? Is the installation media still inside? There should be a little hole by the disk drive. If the disk will not eject try manually ejecting it by carefully inserting a paperclip into this hole.

Comment: choose the option to "boot from hard disk" instead and then choose ubuntu from the grub menu

Answer (score 0):

It should already be installed so it's no big deal, just choose the option to "boot from hard disk" instead and then choose ubuntu from the grub menu.

Your grub menu should show ubuntu and windows to choose from; just choose ubuntu.

You can click on the arrow to eject the disk in your file application.

Comment: It tells me I need to load the kernel first. How would I do that? It says Secure boot forbids loading module from whatever i try to do. I'm very new at ubuntu, so sorry for not knowing much, haha

Comment: you may need to reinstall. however, first, go into your bios settings and disable secureboot

Comment: @Liverian if disabling secureboot fixes the problem then cool, if not, you may also have to reinstall ubuntu but this time, if the disk doesn't eject, don't worry about it just select "boot from hard disk" when you get the disk menu or use a paperclip to eject and then do a hard shutdown using the power button.

Comment: @Liverian why won't it install? where/how does the installation fail?